# When using MongoDB aggregation - How to filter out results with no aggregated children?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, lookup

Trying to wrap my head around aggregation features 
and having trouble figuring out how can I filter out results 
with no aggregated children?

lets say I have `things`:

```
{ _id: abc1, thingColor: "green" }
{ _id: abc2, thingColor: "red" }
{ _id: abc3, thingColor: "amazing" }
```

and I have `birds`:

```
{ _id: 1, thing_id: "abc1", type: "singing", isBiting: false }
{ _id: 2, thing_id: "abc1", type: "notFlying", isBiting: true }
{ _id: 3, thing_id: "abc3", type: "manEating", isBiting: false }
```

now I want to get a list of things, but only those that have at least one bird associated with them by id and only birds that bite.
So basically from this example I would like to get from `things` only:

```
{ _id: abc1, birds_id: "abc1" }
```

My query is like this - querying `things`:

```
  {
    $lookup:
      {
        from: 'birds',
        let: { thingIdVar: '$_id'},
        pipeline: [
          {$match:
              {$expr:
                  {$and: [
                      {$eq: ['$thing_id',  '$$thingIdVar']},
                      {$eq: ['$isBiting',  true]}
                    ]}
              }
          }
        ],
        as: 'birds'
      }
  },
```

this will return the `things` aggregated with the `birds` but it will get back all the things even if they don't have `birds` aggregated.

If I had 1 to 1 `things` to `birds` i could use `{$unwind: '$birds'}`
but each `thing` can have a lot of `birds`

At this point, Im doing the filtering programmatically but this messes up some other stuff (this example is a simplified version).

So I would prefer to get the results from mongo already filtered..

Is there a way to do so??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `$match` stage after the `$lookup`

```
{ "$match": { "birds": { "$ne": [] }}}
```

Since there is no barrier for the parent collection it returns all the  documents. So to filter out the documents (things) which do not contain atleast one `birds` you have to use `$match` stage in the parent collection

Comment: That worked perfectly. Was not aware that the order had any meaning. Thank you. Small related question. In my real query there is a `$match` for `things` so following your answer I placed another `$match` after the `$lookup` -> are there any performance differences if you have 2 `$match` entires?

Comment: `$match` stage should be put as soon as possible in the aggregation pipeline. But as you have already one `$match` stage at the top you don't need to worry. It will not much affect on the performance.

Comment: ok thanks, if you have any resources for learning in depth inner mongo mechanism I would be super happy to hear, can find anything other the "how to use"

Comment: You can only find inside the mongo docs. Please search for aggregation pipeline and it's stages